# performance test between two directions of a 2D array

Tags: c++, image-processing

This code (A) executes much faster (10 times) then the second one:

```
for(int w=0; w<width; w++) {
        for(int h=1; h<height; h++) {
            image[h][w] = (1-a)*image[h][w] + a*image[h-1][w];
        }
    }
```

Second one:

```
for(int h=0; h<height; h++) {
        for(int w=1; w<width; w++) {
            image[h][w] = (1-a)*image[h][w] + a*image[h][w-1];
        }
    }
```

Why is that? it is the same to go through all of the pixels in the image in either horizontal or vertical direction.

Is there a way to speed up the second one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get the loops switched? Unless I'm overlooking something,  I find it hard to believe that the first loop is faster.

Comment: yes, I am sure the first one is about 9,10 times faster!

Comment: And also what are the dimensions you are testing with?

Comment: The higher the image is (compared to its width), the more memory the second loop has to access that the first doesn't.

Comment: Still backwards? Are you sure it's not FORTRAN? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has to do with [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). If you access the elements in the same order as they are stored in memory, this will be much faster than accessing them in a strided pattern, as the memory caches and memory bandwidth will be utilized far more effectively.

The above would explain the second version being faster than the first one, and this is exactly what happens on my box:

```
aix@aix:~$ time ./ver1
real    0m29.421s

aix@aix:~$ time ./ver2
real    0m2.198s
```

Here is the code I use to allocate the array:

```
  double a = 0.5;
  int width = 2048;
  int height = 2048;
  double* data = new double[height * width];
  double** image = new double*[height];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    image[i] = data + i * width;
  }
```

Version 1 times the following loop:

```
  for (int iter = 0; iter < 100; iter++) {
    for(int w=0; w<width; w++) {
      for(int h=1; h<height; h++) {
        image[h][w] = (1-a)*image[h][w] + a*image[h-1][w];
      }
    }
  }
```

Version 2 loop:

```
  for (int iter = 0; iter < 100; iter++) {
    for(int h=0; h<height; h++) {
      for(int w=1; w<width; w++) {
        image[h][w] = (1-a)*image[h][w] + a*image[h][w-1];
      }
    }
  }
```

Compiled with `g++` 4.4.3 with `-O3` and run on a Xeon box of some description (64-bit Ubuntu).

If you are still 100% sure that you're seeing the **opposite** effect, there must be something fundamentally different about what you're doing compared to what I'm doing. It might help if you told us the dimensions of your image and how exactly it gets allocated (in order to help establish the memory layout).

Comment: could you please provide a sample code for above? thanks in advance

Comment: `if you access the elements in the same order as they are stored in memory, this will be much faster`... But according to the OP's claim, its slower. in fact `10` times slower. According to you, the second code should be faster.

Comment: but how to speed it up? @JohnDibling?

Comment: @devn:  Patient: "It hurts when I go like this."  Doctor: "Don't go like that."

Answer (score 1):

aix is right about locality of reference. To be more explicit, this is because of memory hierarchy.

When you first access an element, it's probably a cache miss. An entire cache line is loaded, then the read/write happens.

Depending on which direction you traverse the array in, the next access will either be at location i+1 or i+N. i+1 is likely to be in the same cache line but i+N will generally be in another cache line, demanding another large fetch.

For small N, the whole thing ends up in cache and it doesn't matter much about direction. For suitably large N, not all of the array can fit into the fastest (and smallest) part of the cache, so the cache line containing element i may get dropped before you access i+M*N and have to be reloaded before accessing i+1.

To make it as fast as possible you have to get particular about the CPU architecture. Some are more alignment-sensitive than others. Some prefer you to touch each cache line once (up to capacity) and then do the copying afterwards. Timeslicing and processor sharing mess things up, of course.